# Programmatically convert notebook input cells to text file

Tags: notebooks, conversion

I have ~150 student-submitted *Mathematica* notebooks for an assessed assignment. While I've been marking them, I'm suspecting there is a reasonable amount of plagiarism going on, when multiple students make the same odd errors throughout.

When I find something odd, I can use Notebook++ to search through all the notebooks for where it crops up elsewhere, but the .nb files have a lot of extra `RowBox` and `BoxData` etc.

I'm looking to convert just the input cells from each notebook into a text file, is there a way to do that programmatically?

The answer at: [Converting a notebook to plain text programmatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/converting-a-notebook-to-plain-text-programmatically) shows how to automate the process of saving a single notebook as a text file, but I want just the `"Input"` `Cell`s and can't figure out how to do that.

**Edit:**

The answer from Alexey works generally, except when an integral has been input using the Integral sign on the palette. Running the code:

```
name = "test2.nb"
Export["test.txt", StringJoin[
  Riffle[NotebookImport[name, "Input" -> "Text"], 
   "\n=================\n"]], "Text",  CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"]
```

then makes something strange happen involving a `SubsuperscriptBox` that I can't fix, which makes the output go over two columns, but within the text file:

[image: Text file from the test notebook]

Comment: NotebookImport does what you need. This question is quite close to what you want at the end: [Export of all notebook files as text files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113738/5478)

Comment: KraZug, let me know if there is anything that the linked answer didn't cover.

Comment: Thanks @Kuba, that is close. Any idea on the strange integral sign behaviour I've just added?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Updated to support multiline input cells and syntax errors*

I would avoid linear syntax. Why not use something like the following:

```
inputCellsToText[nb_, textFile_] := Internal`InheritedBlock[
    {SequenceForm},
    SetAttributes[SequenceForm, HoldAll];
    
    Export[
        textFile,
        Flatten[extractInput /@ NotebookImport[nb, "Input"->"HeldInterpretedCell"]],
        "Text"
    ]
]

extractInput[HoldComplete[ExpressionCell[a_List, __]]] := DeleteCases[
    SequenceForm /@ Unevaluated[a],
    SequenceForm[Null]
]
extractInput[HoldComplete[ExpressionCell[a_, __]]] := SequenceForm[a]
```

For example, the following notebook:

```
nb = Uncompress @"1: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";
```

[image]

produces the following text file:

> Integrate[1/(1 + x^2), {x, 0, Infinity}]
>
> 2 + 2
>
> ErrorBox[ErrorBox[RowBox[{RowBox[{"4", " ", "4"}], "+"}]]]
>
> Subscript[x, 2]^3
>
> α^2 + (Element[b, c])

Comment: This works really nicely, except for if there are multiple lines in a single Input Cell they are concatenated together with `Null`. Adding //. HoldComplete[a___, Null, b___] -> 
  Sequence[HoldComplete[a], HoldComplete[b]] before swapping HoldComplete with SequenceForm solves that.
One more wrinkle, if the input line gives a syntax error then you get a Failure[] message.

Comment: @KraZug I updated my answer to use "HeldInterpretedCell" instead so that you can still get syntactically correct lines of input, and I removed the Null objects.

Comment: This is far quicker to run than Alexey's current version, but is giving me ErrorBox's even sometimes when I don't see why. I'll try and get an example sorted later.

Comment: I've just asked a question as to why NotebookImport sometimes fails to import when the code is spread over multiple lines. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146415/notebookimport-and-commands-split-over-multiple-lines

Comment: Is it possible to keep comments that are in the input cells as well? Right now, all comments are stripped out. For example, if I have a notebook with this one input cell  `(*this is a comment*)  x=1;` and run your code on the notebook, the output .txt file will only have `x=1;` in it.  It will be very useful to keep comments if possible. Thanks

Comment: I also just found another big problem. If there is a comment in the input cell, above some code, then all the code in the text file comes out with `(*` spread all over the place!  I put example notebook and the text file it generated in this [folder](https://www.12000.org/tmp/022318/) and as you can see, the output text file is messed up.  I hope it is easy to fix this? It looks like comment is confusing the conversion.

Answer (score 7):

As [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) [say](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/146167/programmatically-convert-notebook-input-cells-to-text-file#comment392839_146167) in the comments, `NotebookImport` does what you need. Specifically, `NotebookImport[nb, "Input" -> "Text"]` preserves the original formatting and syntax of input cells what should fit your purposes exactly. You can `Riffle` the obtained list of strings with some delimiter in order to distinguish different cells in the exported file:

```
StringJoin[Riffle[NotebookImport[nb, _ -> "Text"], "\n=================\n"]]
```

It is easy to automatize the conversion:

```
nbFileNames = FileNames["*.nb"];
Do[
 Export[name <> ".txt",
  StringJoin[Riffle[NotebookImport[name, _ -> "Text"], "\n=================\n"]]
  , "Text"],
 {name, nbFileNames}]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is an improved solution which correctly handles special and Unicode characters as well as 2D typesetting, and encodes everything using the [*linear syntax*](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/xp4fuxv_ODk/tOqGkuy3RWgJ) ([tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/StringRepresentationOfBoxes.html)):

```
nbFileNames = FileNames["*.nb"];

Do[Export[name <> ".txt",
  StringJoin[Riffle[
    ToString[#, InputForm, CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"] & /@
     NotebookImport[name, "Input" -> "Text"],
    "\n=================\n"]],
  "Text"],
 {name, nbFileNames}]
```

The linear syntax has an advantage of being universal, exact and platform-independent representation of a string (which is allowed to contain rich formatting and 2D typesetting) at the expense of substantially lesser readability.

Comment: Thank you. With the specification of "Input" in this code, this generally works. It does need CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII" on the Export to deal with special characters, but I'm having some issues with formatting when there is an Integral sign in the code. See my edit to the question.

Comment: @KraZug I see, would that be acceptable? `Export[...,
  ToString[..., InputForm, CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"], "Text"
  ]`?

Comment: The answer (with the modifications mentioned above, I wasn't sure whether I should just edit them into in) works nicely in general, but fails for the Integral symbol for some reason. I can't get ToString[..., InputForm] to work and give the same kind of result.

Comment: @KraZug please elaborate, what do you expect from the 2D representation of integral in a text file?

Comment: I would be happy for whatever is appropriate, provided it doesn't screw up the rest of the file. It makes the lines after the integral go into two columns in the .txt file

Comment: @KraZug I updated the answer with improved solution based on the above idea by Kuba.

Comment: Edited a new image into the initial post, but will check your improved solution now.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, your improved solution does handle the Integral now, although it makes everything quoted strings which is ugly I can manage with that.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach which offers better readability while maintaining robustness of the method shown in the "UPDATE" section of [previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146169/280) (with only exception to compatibility between different platforms: carriage returns aren't escaped here).

In order to avoid non-ASCII characters in the output file I use here improved `fromCode` function from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146261/280) answer (which converts character codes into *Mathematica*'s ASCII representation of the corresponding characters):

```
fromCode[c_Integer] /; c <= 127 := FromCharacterCode[c];
fromCode[c_Integer] := 
  StringTake[ToString[FromCharacterCode[c], InputForm, 
    CharacterEncoding -> "PrintableASCII"], {2, -2}];
```

The main function:

```
convertNBtoTXT[fileName_String] :=
  Module[{stream, lines, delim = "\n===============\n"},
   stream = OpenWrite[fileName <> ".txt", BinaryFormat -> True];
   lines = NotebookImport[fileName, "Input" -> "Text"];
   WriteString[stream, Sequence @@ fromCode /@ ToCharacterCode[#], delim] & /@ lines;
   Close[stream];
   ];
```

Note the `Sequence @@` trick: writing character-by-character allows to avoid conversion of typesetting into `OutputForm`, and as the result the *linear syntax* is exported exactly as it is present in the string.

Usage:

```
nbFileNames = FileNames["*.nb"];
convertNBtoTXT /@ nbFileNames;
```

In my tests it correctly handles Unicode and special characters as well as 2D typesetting.

The original input cells can be recovered from exported ASCII file using [`` FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/280) as follows:

```
fileName = "document.nb.txt";
delim = "\n===============\n";

NotebookPut[
 Notebook[
  Cell[First@
      MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[#, True]],
     "Input"] & /@
   ReadList[fileName, Record, RecordSeparators -> delim]]]
```

---

**UPDATE**

Using the `ExportAsASCII` function from [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146404/280) answer we can achieve the same in a more efficient way:

```
nbFileNames = FileNames["*.nb"];

Do[
 ExportAsASCII[name <> ".txt", 
  StringJoin[Riffle[NotebookImport[name, "Input" -> "Text"], "\n=================\n"]]],
 {name, nbFileNames}]
```

Comment: Both this method and Carl's method have pros and cons, but I think Carl's is marginally better for what I want, as it converts the special characters as well, which means I can search more naturally on expressions that include symbols like -> or ==. Provided Wolfram fix the bug with splitting expressions across lines!

Comment: Carl's method is still much faster, 14s instead of 329s to do 150 notebooks.