# CMD method to convert .nb file into .m file

Tags: notebooks, packages, conversion, scripting

`.nb` file consists of the boxes, and the `.m` file is a pure text file, what can help to share on [GitHub](https://github.com). Of course, we can open a `.nb` file with *Mathematica*, then `Save As...` it as a `.m` file. But I don't want to cost much time to open the **FrontEnd** to do such thing. If the CMD command can do this, it will help a lot. Is it possible?

I'm using *Windows 10*, of course, if someone provide a method based on other operation system, it is welcome here.

I think use `FilePrint` in `wolframscript` can do this, but actually it is don't work for me.

Comment: Potentially useful `ExportPacket` function here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/363

Comment: If you wish to use GitHub versioning functionality for collaborate work (what normally isn't handy with Wolfram Notebooks), you can try the [“one Cell - one line” code format inside of NB files](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114677/280).

Comment: Strongly related if not a duplicate: "[Programmatically convert notebook input cells to text file](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146167/280)."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I think it is not duplicate, I don't hope to launch *Mathemaitca* in this question.

Comment: Also strongly related: "[Converting a notebook to plain text programmatically](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5488/280)." [This method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5513/280) doesn't use FrontEnd at all.

Comment: For simple Notebooks (with code only inside of input cells) the method shown [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/115400/280) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31157/280) will work (and it doesn't use FrontEnd).

Comment: Related: "[Convert a Notebook directly to a package with boiler plate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/154743/280)."

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following code to convert all `.nb` files in all sub-directories in a root directory `dir` to `.m` files (see also [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113738/export-of-all-notebook-files-as-text-files) ):

```
ChoiceDialog[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[dir], "Directory"], Dynamic[dir]}];
notebookFiles = FileNames["*.nb", dir, Infinity]
num = Length[notebookFiles];

Do[
    file = notebookFiles[[i]];
    notebookText = Import[file, "Text"];

    Export[
      StringDrop[file, -2] <> "m", 
      StringRiffle[NotebookImport[file, "Input" -> "InputText"], "\n"], 
      "Text"
    ];
    , {i, 1, num}
];
```

Comment: Problem is I think yode is explicitly trying to avoid using the FE. Can `NotebookImport` work without it?

Comment: @ b3m2a1: As I understand Yode does not not want to do the conversion by opening each notebook and then saving over the menu, because it is too much time consuming if one has a lot of notebooks. The code I show above can be executed in an external notebook and converts all your notebook files to .m files at once.

Comment: Ah I see. I thought he wanted a CLI solution.

Comment: Yes, I just don't open *Mathematica* to do it. I hope to use command method.